# In an MS Access Maketable query, how to create an Autonumber field?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Maketable query in an Access db that could use an Autonumber field.  I can't find a built-in function for my purpose.  Do i need to write my own? Ideally, I'd just like to create a field in the Access designer as "Autonum: CreateAutoNumber()"

Edit: If it can't be done in the query itself, I can also run a procedure afterward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reckon you either need to use TableDefs or DDL. The DDL query would run after the maketable query, for example:

```
 ALTER TABLE NewTable ADD COLUMN AutoField COUNTER
```

EDIT Additional note

If you wish to make the new column the primary key, you can run something like:

```
ALTER TABLE NewTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (AutoField)
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  I'm a little surprised this question hasn't been asked before on stackoverflow.

Comment: Why would the vast majority of Access users need DDL to do something as simple as adding an Autonumber field to a table? The point of Access is that it makes these kinds of things discoverable through its UI so you don't need to know SQL to get the job done, so in general the only people asking this kind of question are people who are either not using Access at all (they are only using Jet/ACE as a data store) and don't have Access installed, or are so clever that they've never bothered to learn how to use all the useful tools that Access provides out of the box.

Comment: Sorry, David, I don't quite understand. Are you suggesting a better solution than Remou's? Or are you just commenting on MS Access's functionality in general?

Comment: I'm suggesting opening up Access and making the changes to the table through the Access UI, instead of running DDL SQL to do the same thing. The latter is useful when you don't have Access, but it seems to me to be overkill for something so simple as this when you have it and when it's not something that has to be automated (e.g., you need to do this with dozens of tables in many different databases). That's my explanation of why it's not been seldome asked about, because Access users don't need DDL to do this kind of thing, thus, not question about it.

Comment: When it can be done manually, I agree.  But in this case, it does need to be automated.  So Remou's answer is ideal.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton, there are many reasons the process should be automated, not just being done on many tables. If it's required for transforming the data in a way that you want end-users to be able to utilise without having to mess about with table structures.

Comment: I needed this automated statement to adjust the database model in preparation for moving the data to a new database model in a different platform entirely.

Answer (score 3):

make your life simple, create a delete query followed by an append query, then use a macro to run them.
if you need the autonumbering to start from 1 every time, create another query from your table with an extra column with the following code idnew:dcount("[id]","mytable","[id]<"&[id])
hope this helps.

Comment: Looking back at this question, your suggestion is exactly what I would do today: replace the maketable query with a delete query and an append query so that the table always exists and the fields are always of the same type. It's also better because the destination table was then used as a source for other queries.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use vba

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_YourTable ADD [ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an empty table containing your schema (use table design or copy existing table without data) and add an Autonumber field.  Call this table yourtable_FORMAT
2. Copy yourtable_FORMAT to yourtable (each time you want to do a make table)
3. APPEND records to yourtable. (This causes the Autonumber field to always restart at 1.)

(This process also lets you append LOTS of tables together without using a UNION command.)